# Hide/remove column on smaller screens

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to hide/remove the first column if the screen size goes below around 768px.

```
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start">
      ...
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Am I missing something that will allow this to happen from my code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the `fxHide` to hide the columns when you go below the threshold size. In your case, it should be `fxHide.lt-sm`, where `lt` means *less than* and `sm` means *small*

```html
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxHide.lt-sm>
      ...
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxHide.lt-sm>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, some other styling was not causing this to work for me. I removed and can see it working

Answer (score 0):

You can use **css** styles to achieve that.

Some thing like:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row {
        .col:first-child {
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```